# Do monoid homomorphisms from $X^X$ to a group factor through $\text{Sym}(X)$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $X$ be a set and let $(X^X,\circ)$ denote the monoid of all maps $f: X\to X$, together with composition. Let $(\text{Sym}(X),\circ)$ be the group of all bijections from $X$ to itself.

Does there exist a monoid homomorphism $h:X^X \to \text{Sym}(X)$ such that for every group $G$ and every monoid homomorphism $f: X^X\to G$ there is a homomorphism $f': \text{Sym}(X)\to G$ such that $f = f'\circ h$?

Comment: No. For example the identity map $X^X \to X^X$ don't factor through $Sym(X)$ for  a finite set $X$ because $Sym(X)$ has less elements than $X^X$.

Comment: $X^X$ is not a group in your example (I require $G$ above to be a group).

Comment: oh, I see, sorry.

Comment: You are asking the backward universal property. If M is a monoid, then its group of units is the universal group with a morphism INTO $M$.  So any homomorphism from a group $G$ into $M$ factors through $Sym(X)$. If a monoid contains a right or left zero, all its group images are trivial.

Comment: BTW, of you ask for uniqueness of $f'$ the answer is no because for the trivial homomorphism $X^X$ to $Sym(X)$ you have two extensions: the identity and the trivial homomorphism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes for trivial reasons. Let $c$ be a constant map. Then for any two $f$ in $X^X$ we have $ c \circ f = c$. Hence the image of $f$ under any homomorphism to a group must be trivial.

Comment: By the way -- why have you both answered and voted to close?

Comment: I agree with Stefan, especially insofar as the answer easily fits in a comment.

Comment: @StefanKohl For a few reasons: (1) When I first saw the question, I voted to close. When I saw it had an upvote and no other close votes, I thought maybe it wouldn't be closed, and thus it would be better to be answered than to remain an unanswered question. (2) When I first started typing the answer, it was a little longer (I thought the argument would have to first show every function was equivalent to a constant function, then show all constants are equivalent), not all at once. (3) I knew Dominic was unlikely to rephrase the question after seeing it answered in the comments.

Comment: @YCor That said, I would be willing to delete this answer.